# Imports or Long Class format?

Tags: .net, vb.net, import

Should I use this.

```
Imports System.IO

Dim myStream As New Stream
```

or this..

```
Dim myStream As New System.IO.Stream
```

Does it make any difference to performance / memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference whatsoever - it's just a matter of taste and affects readability only.

By the way, CLR is not even aware of the concept of "namespaces": namespace names become prefixes to type names.

Comment: Exactly, namespaces are just to save our fingers from extra typing and to differentiate when naming conflicts occur within a project.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.Net you have a third option:

```
Dim myStream As New IO.Stream
```

You can't do that in C#.  For the IO namespace I almost always use that shortcut, since "IO." isn't that much extra to type.  For most other namespaces I tend to add a using statement at the top of the file.

Comment: You can do this in c# 3 with "var myStream = new IO.Stream();"

Comment: Can you? I'll have to go check at home tonight (only have .Net 2.0 here at work).  I know that with 2.0 this just isn't possible in C#.

Answer (score 1):

What is more readable to you?  I always find it best to import the namespace you need so that you type names are shorter in your code.

Namespaces have no effect on memory or performance - they simply exist to prevent ambiguity between types in a global space.